# compact support of a function?

Tags: real-analysis

For $i = 1,2,3,\ldots$, let $\varphi_i$ be a continuously differentiable function in $R^1$, have support in $(2^{-i},2^{1 - i})$, and have $\int \varphi_i = 1$. Then, let $f(x,y) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty [\varphi_i(x) - \varphi_{i + 1}(x)]\varphi_i(y)$. I'm supposed to show that $f$ has a compact support in $R^2$ and that it's continuous except at $(0,0)$.

I'm kind of confused as to what exactly $f$ is: it seems to me that $f$ should almost always be $0$, and should be $0$ when either $x$ or $y$ equals $2^{-k}$ for any natural $k$. In fact, it seems to me that $f$ should be $0$ except when $x$ and $y$ are both in the same $(2^{-i},2^{1 - i})$ interval, in which case $f(x,y) = \varphi_i(x)\varphi_i(y)$. Given that, I'm not sure what compact interval $f$ might have support in, or how it could be continuous. None of this seems right, so I assume I'm just seriously overlooking something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The support of the $i$th term $[\varphi_i(x) - \varphi_{i + 1}(x)]\varphi_i(y)$ is contained in the rectangle $$R_i = [2^{-i-1},2^{-i+1}]\times [2^{-i}, 2^{-i+1}]$$
Therefore, the support of $f$ is contained in the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Given a point $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$, pick a neighborhood $U$ of this point such that $(0,0)\notin \overline{U}$. Observe that $U$ meets only finitely many of the rectangles $R_i$. Therefore, within $U$ the function $f$ is a finite sum of continuous functions, hence continuous.

It remains to show that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. In fact, it's not even bounded in any neighborhood of $(0,0)$. The reason is that $\max\varphi_i\ge 2^i$.